# Unknown NULL value accessed

Tags: c, null, binary-search-tree, nullreferenceexception

this a partial program of AVL tree, but right now its just more of a BST

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
    int data;
    int height;
    node *left;
    node *right;
} *root = NULL, *temp = NULL;

int max(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;
}

node *new_node(int value)
{
    temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->height = 0;
    return temp;
}
int get_height(node *x)
{
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return x->height;
}

node *insert(node *r, int value)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        return new_node(value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value < r->data)
            r->left = insert(r->left, value);
        else
            r->right = insert(r->right, value);

        int height = max(get_height(r->left), get_height(r->right)) + 1;
}

void inorder(node *r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(r->left);
    printf("node = %d, height = %d\n", r->data, r->height);
    inorder(r->right);
}

void main()
{
    root = insert(root, 10);
    root = insert(root, 20);
    inorder(root);
}
```

The output of this program is following, as I'm not accessing any NULL values -

```
node = 10, height = 1
node = 20, height = 0
```

after just adding one line, I'm accessing a NULL value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
    int data;
    int height;
    node *left;
    node *right;
} *root = NULL, *temp = NULL;

int max(int n1, int n2)
{
    return n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2;
}

node *new_node(int value)
{
    temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->height = 0;
    return temp;
}
int get_height(node *x)
{
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return x->height;
}

node *insert(node *r, int value)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        return new_node(value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value < r->data)
            r->left = insert(r->left, value);
        else
            r->right = insert(r->right, value);

        int height = max(get_height(r->left), get_height(r->right)) + 1;
    int balance_factor = get_height(r->left)- get_height(r->right); // extra line added

  }
}

void inorder(node *r)
{
    if (r == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(r->left);
    printf("node = %d, height = %d\n", r->data, r->height);
    inorder(r->right);
}

void main()
{
    root = insert(root, 10);
    root = insert(root, 20);
    inorder(root);
}
```

Now my program is just hanging, its not an infinite call/ loop. It is surely a NULL value access. But how is this even possible?

Comment: Where exactly is it hanging? Use a debugger to help you find that out immediately and also trace the execution of your program. Finally, note that C and C++ are different languages so use only the tag you are actually programming in.

Comment: `malloc` and `NULL` in a C++ program - really?

Comment: pardon me, I removed C++ tag. Its a C code. @kaylum

Comment: And how about where does it hang?

Comment: `insert` looks wrong. It doesn't return anything in the `else` path.

Comment: Just adding one line(specified line) makes it hang, Its surely a bug in Inorder function because as Im commenting the call to inorder its working fine.

Comment: Don't guess! Use a debugger. Looks like your `insert` does not return a value in some cases so that will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: insert was wrong @kaylum, fixed it. its now working like a charm

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: I'll use debugger from now on wards.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not sure about NULL, but we can surely use malloc in C++ also.

Comment: @pyskmr Of course you *can* use it. But you usually *should not*. `malloc` doesn't call object constructors for example. Same with `NULL` - sure, you *can*, but you *should* be using `nullptr` instead.

Comment: please check `insert` has right parentheses ?

Comment: Post true code.  `node *insert(node *r, int value)` missing `}`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ok jesper noted, surely take that as an info while working in C++.

Comment: Copy and paste the code that fails, because thi is not it because this won't compile.  `insert()` is missing a `}' at least.

Comment: `node *insert(node *r, int value)` is not returning in case of `root` non-null.

Comment: This, to me, looks like C code compiled with a C++ compiler. *Not* how one would write modern C++ at all.

Comment: How should I stop this now, I got the answer..lol Im not so old here, pardon me moderator please don't disable anything.

Comment: Your use of global variables is unnecessary and dangerous BTW.

Comment: OT: the function `main()` has only two valid signatures (regardless of what visual studio will allow)  Those signatures are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv] )`  Notice they both return an `int` value,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging by forum/Q&A is never efficient.  Use a debugger:

For example at https://onlinegdb.com/S1ZansZNU

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.                                                                                   
/usr/share/gdb/gdbinit: No such file or directory.                                                                   
(gdb) run                                                                                                            
Starting program: /home/a.out                                                                                        

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                 
0x0000000000400703 in inorder (r=0xffffffff) at main.c:62                                                            
62          inorder(r->left);                                                                                        
(gdb)
```

`r` is not NULL, but neither is it a valid address.

The problem is clearly in:

```
root = insert(root, 10);
```

when insert does not explicitly return a value

Answer (score 2):

Function `insert` is not returning any pointer in case of `r != NULL` collecting a return value when function is not returning anything is undefined behavior.

i.e

```
root = insert(root, 10);//it is returning valid pointer
root = insert(root, 20);//unknown value copied to root
```

please update your code as follows,

```
node *insert(node *r, int value)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        return new_node(value);
    }
    //rest of the logic     
    return r;//missing from both of your snippet
}
```

Refer for more details on [UB](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)